# PF tagging then adding to table

Tags: networking, freebsd, pf

could someone please provide an example on how to add a tagged packet to a table? I have found commands to do it from the command line but can you setup a specific rule to do it inside of pf.conf?

Thanks.

This is all in regards to PF...

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can.

Nor do I understand why you'd need to.

Your second rule (once already tagged) would just operate on the tag rather than a table.

It might help for you to include an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I would like to just ban an IP that is attempting to connect to a certain port. I thought tagging might be the easiest way to achieve this, and make the rules readable because through the ruleset I could be tagging packets I would like to ban at the end.